# MongoDB connecting to Node on AWS Mean stack

Tags: mongodb, mean

I have been trying for a few days to connect my mongoDB to MEAN stack without success.  Its running on AWS lightsail (Bitnami).  The website itself is running fine, except for any pages that have an ajax/db call, as the database is not connecting/authenticating my connection string.

I am using the mongo,node, express part of the stack, I do not need or know any angular at present. I thought this would be easier than setting up on nodeJS and then adding mongoDB separately (well i did try that first with similar problems), I do intend to learn angualar in future so this is probably better long term.  Server side set up is currently a weakness.

I am using mongoose for the connection.  I can access the database using:
mongo admin --username root -p password via SSH.

I can also access the db via Rockmongo SSH.  There is currently only one admin user in the database at present i.e. root.

My initial server/startup file is below:

server.js

```
const app = require('/opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/app.js');

require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

const mongoose    = require("mongoose");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;  

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CONN);

app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Server has started!");
 });
```

variables.env

```
DATABASE_CONN = mongodb://root:password@127.0.0.1:27017/MYAPPDATABASE
```

I have also tried many other connections strings, exchanging root for bitnami default user, etc.

When I go to my app folder and start the server (npm start or node server.js), the website starts up but with the below mongoDB authentication errors, below is only the first section.

```
> Server has started!
Connection error: { MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at /opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/con
nection/pool.js:595:61
    at authenticateStragglers (/opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modu
les/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:513:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/node_modules/mongoose/node_m
odules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:549:5)
    at emitMessageHandler (/opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/
mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/MYAPP/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/
mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Authentication failed.',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Authentication failed.',
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed' }
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.  Thank you kindly.

Mos.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Solution found.

1. In the mongo.conf file I set the dbpath to /data/db
2. The mongo shell is pointed to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock "$@"

go to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo
change /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock "$@" **to** /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock "$@"

Can do that using sudo nano /opt/bitnami/mongodb/bin/mongo then edit the file.

Still have noauth turned on, so next step is getting my db connection string to authenticate.

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement.  I have edited mongo.conf for now to enable no auth.  I then ran mongod which stated no /data/db folder for which it stores data.  So I created the folders and ran mongod again.  Now all pages work but the mongo shell command 'mongo' will not work on the terminal.

I think its because the mongod dbpath is set to data/db and the mongodb conf file dbpath is set to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db.

So I am trying to update the mongod dbpath but it doesnt seem to update.